# What is the most popular resolution in use in your company?

Tags: screen-resolution

What is the most popular resolution in use in your company? Our is 1440 x 900 (15" widescreen).

Is anyone using 1024x768 or less anymore? I'm sure there odd machines here and there but I'd have thought >1024x768 is not popular, am I right?

Finally what's the lowest resolution you have in general use?

Thanks

Comment: I do not miss the days when we had to design for 800x600, and still make it acceptable in 640x480. Bring on 2160p!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1024*768 is a lot less common than it once was but it is still common enough to be considered for things such as web design (i.e. "it should look right on 1024*768 or higher, and degrade gracefully on lower"). It is the most common resolution on non wide-screen laptops for instance. Most new non-widescreen monitors are 17" or 19" and have a native resolution of 1280*1024 (5:4 aspect ratio), but larger models often have larger resolutions (those these aren't overly common). Widescreen resolutions are a lot more varied though. In my limited experience 1680*1050 (16:10) is most common in new monitors at the moment, closely followed by 1920*1080 (16:9) for screens over 22". For small screens (and some larger screens that are primarily intented to be TVs) you will find that 1280*720 is not uncommon. The many mobile and otherwise small-form-factor devices available muddy the waters much further though.

The lowest in general use where I work is 1024*768 (a couple of laptops, the newest being ~18 months old). The lowest on the desktop is 1280*1024. On my desk at home I have 1920*1050 and 1050*1680 (a widescreen monitor rotated 90 degrees is a wonderfuly useful thing sometimes). The smallest though is my netbook at 1024*600 (or sometimes 600*1024), which is used at times for both work and play.

If you are asking because you are planning some sort of design that might be screen resolution/size sensitive, I would recommend that you aim quite small as your lowest common denominator and try make sure your design looks good (or at least good enough) on a range of screen sizes. Long gone are the days when there was only two or three screen resolutions to worry about in the general populous - there are many screen sizes that are common enough to be considered popular.

Answer (score 5):

Our "most popular" is the native resolution of the LCD screen itself. As we have many different models of screens, the resolution varies greatly.

Comment: Same here - Pretty much everyone runs their displays at native resolution.  All of our software is designed to operate at a minimum resolution of 1024x768 for legacy compatibility though.

Comment: Thanks, we too run at native res but as there are various 15" and 17" monitors (wide/non wide etc) I was interested in the res. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @Scott: If you wanted to know "what should I design a webpage for" then should should have asked that question. Don't beat around the bush and you might actually get the sort of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, both where I work and places I visit, resolution varies for a number of reasons.

- Some applications don't scale to suit the window size, so people who use such applications tend to have lower resolutions
- Programmers, artists and CAD users generally prefer quite high resolutions
- Older people generally use lower resolutions than younger folk, as eyesight degrades with age
- Those doing secretarial type work mostly use lower resolutions and they, more than any other group, will rotate their screen through 90 degrees to better display documents

Personally, for a 19 inch monitor I like it around 1280 x whatever suits the screen proportions but sit fairly close to it because of the aging eyes issue.

The web site stats that I have access to indicate that 1280x1024 is the most common, with 1024x768 still being used quite a lot. Of course this will depend greatly on the type of person the web site tends to be used by. There is however a very definite trend towards higher resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

In my small company there are only LCD's with native resolution 1650x1080 (including laptops).
We also use netbooks with 1024x600.

When upgrading to new laptops we will buy FullHD 1920x1080.

Comment: Man what kind of budget do you have for laptops when you can buy full HD monitors?

Comment: We consider needs and the laptops are our tools. Programmers do like big resolutions :)

Answer (score 0):

The most popular resolution in our office is the one that the user sets for themselves. ;)

Comment: Like "do more exercise" and "lose weight"?

Comment: LOL. That made me chuckle. ;)

Answer (score 0):

1280 x 1024 for the locked down users on 19inch standard monitors

Answer (score 0):

I had a tablet laptop I inherited last year that had a 1024x768 display, but most desktop monitors have 1280x1024 as a minimum.  This was not due to choice, but rather due to the corporate IT purchasing decision.  In some cases developers or other heavy users would have a two of these 1280x1024 displays.

Like anyone who works with a number of machines, though, I often use Remote Desktop or am hosting a VM, and those screens can be often be 1024x768 or less.

Answer (score 0):

1280x1024 is probably by far the most popular.  We do however have a number of users who are visually impaired and need to run at *much* lower resolutions (in addition to using magnification or screen reading software).  If you're going to use the responses to this for guaging design of a website or application, you really need to take that into account.